# Not Able to print any string after ellipsis character

Tags: c++, special-characters

Consider the simple snippet of the code which prints two strings

"Before ellipsis" and  "After ellipsis" separated by the character ellipsis.
Surprisingly string "After ellipsis" is not printed in the console

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        wcout<< "Before ellipsis" << endl;
        wcout << L"…" << endl;
        wcout << "L After ellipsis" << endl;
        return 0;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Actually, the string `"Before ellipsis"` should not be printed either, as it's not a wide-character string. Just like `"L After ellipsis"` is not a wide-character string.

Comment: The string "Before ellipsis" is printed and later if ellipsis is removed 
string "L After ellipsis" is printed too.